# ASP.net ACTK DragPanel Extender on PopupControlExtender with UpdatePanel does not drag after partial postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I have a panel on an aspx page which contains an UpdatePanel.

This panel is wrapped with both a PopUpControl Extender as well as a DragPanel Extender.

Upon initial show everything works fine, the panel pops up and closes as expected and can be dragged around as well.

There is a linkbutton within the UpdatePanel which triggers a partial postback.  I originally wanted to use an imagebutton but had a lot of trouble with that so ended up using the linkbutton which works.

Once the partial postback is complete I can no longer drag the panel around.

I would love to hear suggestions on how to fix this.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

What did you do about it?

Do you know of any other way to accomplish this combination of features without employing other third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at when the drag panel extender and popup control extender actually extend your panel.

Chances are those extenders work on an initialization event of the page. When the update panel fires and updates your page the original DOM element that was extended was replaced by the result of the update panel. Which means that you now have a control that is no longer extended.

I don't really know of an easy solution to this problem. What will probably work is if you can hook into an event after the update panel has updated the page and extend the panel again.